# FirebaseRecyclerAdapter is not displaying data in my RecyclerView layout

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

Please note there are lot of questions like these but none of them worked for me.
I have been trying to display data in a recycler view and it isnt displaying the data and not throwing any errors
Here is my code.

I have included the latest version of Firebase Dependencies and Latest version of Firebase UI Database

**Dependencies Version**

```
// Firebase
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.1'

// Firebase UI
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:6.0.2'
```

This is the Films class
**Films.java**

```
package com.dipeshpatil.in;

public class Films {

    public String name, year;

    public Films(String name, String year) {
        this.name = name;
        this.year = year;
    }

    public Films() {

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(String year) {
        this.year = year;
    }
}
```

This is the ViewHolder Class **FilmsViewHolder.java**

```
package com.dipeshpatil.in;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class FilmsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView mFilmName;
    public TextView mFilmYear;

    public FilmsViewHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);

        mFilmName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_name);
        mFilmYear = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_status);
    }
}
```

This is the activity where i am supposed to display the data in recycler view **FilmsActivity.java**

```
public class FilmsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView mFilmsList;
    private DatabaseReference mFilmsDatabase;
    private FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Films> options;
    private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Films, FilmsViewHolder> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_films);

        mFilmsList = findViewById(R.id.films_list);
        mFilmsList.setHasFixedSize(true);

        mFilmsDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Films");

        options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Films>()
                .setQuery(mFilmsDatabase, Films.class)
                .build();

        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Films, FilmsViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(FilmsViewHolder filmsViewHolder, int i, Films films) {

                filmsViewHolder.mFilmName.setText(films.getName());
                filmsViewHolder.mFilmYear.setText(films.getYear());
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public FilmsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

                View mView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.users_single_layout, parent, false);

                return new FilmsViewHolder(mView);
            }
        };
        mFilmsList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }
}
```

Now honestly i am not getting any kind of error which would help me debug the code and check for problems and at the same time it is also not displaying my desired output

**Firebase Database for Films**

```
"Films" : {
    "01" : {
      "name" : "The Prestige",
      "year" : 2002
    },
    "02" : {
      "name" : "Fight Club",
      "year" : 1999
    }
}
```

Layout File **activity_films.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".FilmsActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/films_list" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If you set breakpoints in `onCreateViewHolder` and `onBindViewHolder` and run the code in a debugger, does it reach those breakpoints?

Comment: Have you set a layoutmanager in xml for your recyclerview?

Comment: @BlueJones i've added the layout file in the post now please check it once

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen no i havent learnt to use a debugger so i dont have any idea about it

Comment: yeah you're missing the layout manager in your recyclerview, can add in xml `app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"`
 or programatically as Md. Asaduzzaman has stated below

Comment: @BlueJones thankyou atlast it worked! it needed a layoutManager

Comment: @dipesh-patil glad i could help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert
>   value of type java.lang.Long to String

**First of all,** it's should be a `InvocationTargetException` [**according your database structure**] as you try to cast `Long` as `String` in your model. Try to update your model like below:

```
public class Films {
    public String name;
    public int year;

    ....
}
```

**Then,** You should set `LayoutManager` to your `RecyclerView`

```
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
mFilmsList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
```

**Update:** You have to update your `onBindViewHolder` to convert `int` to **String** before setting it to **TextView** using `String.valueOf`

```
@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(FilmsViewHolder filmsViewHolder, int i, Films films) {

    filmsViewHolder.mFilmName.setText(films.getName());
    filmsViewHolder.mFilmYear.setText(String.valueOf(films.getYear()));
}
```

Comment: I did the changes as you said now it is throwing errors and the app is crashing
this is the error that im getting
`E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.dipeshpatil.in, PID: 1880
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7d2
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:363)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6484)
        at com.dipeshpatil.in.FilmsActivity$1.onBindViewHolder(FilmsActivity.java:46)
        at com.dipeshpatil.in.FilmsActivity$1.onBindViewHolder(FilmsActivity.java:41)
`

Comment: Use `String.valueOf(films.getYear())` inside `onBindViewHolder`

Comment: thankyou atlast it worked! it needed a layoutManager

Answer (score 0):

I think there's usually a delay in when you get a response back from the Firebase query. Thats probably whats happening. By the time you initialize the adapter, the "options" list is still empty.

You will most likely need to use thread synchronization to do this.

Comment: The `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` takes care of that asynchronous loading, and calls `notifyDataSetChanged` when the data is available/changed.

Comment: oh okay, well thanks for the clarification. I was under the impression that you have to manage that yourself!